# Problem with importing tf_agents.environments

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

```
I get this error report:
    ...
      File "C:\Users\larsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\nest.py", line 68, in <module>
        assert_same_structure = dm_tree.assert_same_structure
    AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'assert_same_structure'
```

I have tried updating dm_tree. Its already at 0.1.7. I have also installed the nightly versions of tensorflow and tf_agents.

Comment: please make sure your traceback is readable. Thank Talha for the edit...

Comment: I see it now. New at this.

Comment: For some reason it helped to move the file from the folder I had it in to the Python310 folder. Since this type of problem never has occured before this seems strange. But it did work.

Comment: Yeah sometimes the weirdest solutions are the best ones. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`assert_same_structure` is submodule of `tf.nest`. So you need to give the correct alias name [tf.nest.assert_same_structure()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/nest/assert_same_structure) to access and use this api which syntax is given below:

```
tf.nest.assert_same_structure(
    nest1, nest2, check_types=True, expand_composites=False
)
```